# Why doesn't 'conda' or 'jupyter notebook' work when I use conda to change environments?

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, conda

When I change environments using

```
>conda activate myenv
```

I can't use conda to get back and jupyter notebook doesn't work.

Is something going on with the path when I change environments?

edit: looks like installing notebook (conda install nb_conda) fixes the second problem, and changing the global environment path fixes the first, but I'm still confused about why.

Why does conda work from base, while I need to add ..user.. ..\anaconda3 to my path to make it work from inside myenv?

I'm also getting an internal server error when I activate the conda tab, which (the tab) was never there before.

Comment: This shouldn't be happening. Can you please include the value of `PATH` before and after activation? Also, include the output from `conda info` so we know some context.

Answer (score 0):

You can change system path:

Go to `Control Panel\System and Security\System`, and click on `Advanced system settings` in the left panel.

Click on `Environment variables` on the bottom of the window that opens.

A new window will open, in the bottom section (system variables) find `path`. Double click on that and change it as you like (e.g. if you want to add conda path)